# How to get Nintegrate of multi-dimensional oscillatory function to converge?

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics

So I have the following integral I wish to compute. The constants required are defined as:

```
p=0.05 
L=30*10^(-9)
w=600*10^-9
\[Delta] = 1/100

    swvmesh={-0.495, -0.485, -0.475, -0.465, -0.455, -0.445, -0.435, -0.425,
-0.415, -0.405, -0.395, -0.385, -0.375, -0.365, -0.355, -0.345, \
-0.335, -0.325, -0.315, -0.305, -0.295, -0.285, -0.275, -0.265, \
-0.255, -0.245, -0.235, -0.225, -0.215, -0.205, -0.195, -0.185, \
-0.175, -0.165, -0.155, -0.145, -0.135, -0.125, -0.115, -0.105, \
-0.095, -0.085, -0.075, -0.065, -0.055, -0.045, -0.035, -0.025, \
-0.015, -0.005, 0.005, 0.015, 0.025, 0.035, 0.045, 0.055, 0.065, \
0.075, 0.085, 0.095, 0.105, 0.115, 0.125, 0.135, 0.145, 0.155, 0.165, \
0.175, 0.185, 0.195, 0.205, 0.215, 0.225, 0.235, 0.245, 0.255, 0.265, \
0.275, 0.285, 0.295, 0.305, 0.315, 0.325, 0.335, 0.345, 0.355, 0.365, \
0.375, 0.385, 0.395, 0.405, 0.415, 0.425, 0.435, 0.445, 0.455, 0.465, \
0.475, 0.485, 0.495}
x[i_]:= swvmesh[[i]]
```

The integral I want to compute is given by:

```
 NIntegrate[ -w^2(( t^2 ((a - b)^2 + t^2 + p^2) - p^2 (a - b)^2)/(
    Sqrt[(a - b)^2 + t^2 + p^2] ((a - b)^2 + t^2)^2) - 
    t^2/(Sqrt[(a - b)^2 + t^2])^3) Cos[k t]/(\[Pi] L) , {t, 
  0, \[Infinity]}, {b, x[i] - \[Delta]/2, x[i] + \[Delta]/2}, {a, 
  x[i] - \[Delta]/2, x[i] + \[Delta]/2}]-\[Delta]
```

The values of x[i] in the integral shouldnt matter too much since the result should be the same regardless for x[i]. I know for k=0, I expect that the result should be -1.18898*10^-9. I have no idea how to make this converge or produce something reasonable. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You can evaluate the `a` and `b` integrals symbolically with the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.  `Integrate` might not compute the definite integral directly.  It gets bogged down in checking convergence or branches or something, and I did not wait to see if it would come up with something.  OTOH `Integrate` returns the antiderivative rather quickly.  We can numerically check the result at the end. (I dropped the `-δ` from after the integral, since without it we get integrals on the order of `10^-9`, which around the size the OP expects.)

```
p = 5/100;  (* use exact parameters, esp. with Integrate[] *)

aint = Integrate[-w^2 ((t^2 ((a - b)^2 + t^2 + p^2) - 
       p^2 (a - b)^2)/(Sqrt[(a - b)^2 + t^2 + 
         p^2] ((a - b)^2 + t^2)^2) - 
    t^2/(Sqrt[(a - b)^2 + t^2])^3) Cos[k t]/(π L), a];
aint = aint /. {{a -> a1}, {a -> a2}} // Differences // First;

bint = Integrate[aint, b];
bint = bint /. {{b -> b1}, {b -> b2}} // Differences // First;

Block[{i = 1, k = 0, a1, a2, b1, b2},
 a1 = x0 - δ/2; a2 = x0 + δ/2;
 b1 = x0 - δ/2; b2 = x0 + δ/2;
 Integrate[bint, {t, 0, ∞}]  (* or use NIntegrate *)
 ]
(*  -((3 (10 ArcTan[5] - 25 Log[5] + 12 Log[13] + Log[4096]))/(2500000000 π))  *)

N[%]
(*  -4.81102*10^-9  *)
```

If we execute the OP's integral as below, we get very nearly the same result `-4.8108*10^-9` with an error estimate `1.30357*^-11` that is large enough for `NIntegrate` to complain that the `PrecisionGoal` is not met.  The `NIntegrate::eincr` raises the question of whether the integration has begun to converge, but I think the agreement of the two methods suggests that `-4.8*^-9` is close to the correct answer. It's not exactly close to what the OP reports is expected, but the numerical agreement tends to confirm the validity of the exact result in my opinion.

```
Block[{i = 1, k = 0, wp = 16},
 NIntegrate[
   SetPrecision[
    -w^2 ((t^2 ((a - b)^2 + t^2 + p^2) - 
          p^2 (a - b)^2)/(Sqrt[(a - b)^2 + t^2 + 
            p^2] ((a - b)^2 + t^2)^2) - 
       t^2/(Sqrt[(a - b)^2 + t^2])^3) Cos[k t]/(π L),
    wp],
   {t, 0, ∞},
   {b, x[i] - δ/2, x[i] + δ/2},
   {a, x[i] - δ/2, b, x[i] + δ/2},
   WorkingPrecision -> wp
   ] // Hold[#] &
 ]
```

> NIntegrate::slwcon: ....
>
> NIntegrate::eincr: ...NIntegrate obtained -4.81082853784813491066945224884726773959052943961877387033785106166*10^-9 and 1.30357246887625736388131163973251350180788153573818344944799771445`66.*^-11 for the integral and error estimates.

```
(*  Hold[-4.810828537848135*10^-9]  *)
```

The integral as a function of `k`:

```
ClearAll[int];
int[k0_?NumericQ, x0_?NumericQ] :=
  Block[{k = k0, a1, a2, b1, b2},
   a1 = x0 - δ/2; a2 = x0 + δ/2;
   b1 = x0 - δ/2; b2 = x0 + δ/2;
   NIntegrate[bint, {t, 0, ∞}] 
   ];

ListLinePlot@Table[{kk, int[kk, xxx[1]]}, {kk, 0, 1, 1/64}]
```

[image]

Comment: This works fantastic. Would you have any suggestions to compute this say for non-zero k, ie k=0.006.

Comment: @user217 For the third integral (inside Block[] in my answer) you can replace Integrate[] by NIntegrate[]. I won't be able to try it out for a while, but 1D integrals are easier to handle numerically than higher dimensional ones.

Answer (score 0):

Trying

- local adaptive integration (or other methods),
- no singularity handling,
- using smaller precision goals, or
- rationalizing the involved number constants and using larger working precision

might produce results you want. See the attached screenshot showing some convergent results.

(I did not analyze the integral, just tried some different options...)

[image]